# Write XML directly to disk and append elements

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, file-io, xmlwriter

I am trying to write an XML file but it is too large to store in memory, thus I want to write to it directly to disk. I have tried using XmlWriter but there is not functionality to enable me to append to the end of the file, hence I am willing to resort to writing the XML raw using a regular file writer.

Does anyone know of any file writing classes that enable me to write straight to disk and which enable me to overwrite positions inside the file?

The reason is that I need to be able to write over the closing of the root element so that I may append another bit of information, but also be able to read the XML file when needed. For example, if I had the following XML:

```
<elements>
  <element>
  </element>
</elements>
```

If I wanted to read this, I could, but if I want to write to it I must first delete the `</elements>` tag, append another element, and then append the closing tag again.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is rather unfortunate that XML was designed in such a way as to make appending impossible.

Comment: How large is the file, and what are your memory constraints?

Comment: My memory contraint is the 1.5GB limit of the .NET runtime, and the file is incredibly large. I have yet to find out how large it will get, but many GBs is expected.

Comment: I would think you can open a stream to the file, seek to the end, build an XmlWriter and pass the stream to Create...does this not work?

Comment: What about [Memory Mapper Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)? But you will write not directly to a disk but first to a MMF which is stored in Virtual Memory

Comment: @sll that might improve overall I/O performance but will not help in the OP's case.  He can't use a DOM model because he is memory constrained, so he has to use SAX-style I/O, and his concern was how to position the writer correctly.

Comment: I have to say, it seems xml isn't the best way to store this data.  Is it possible to change the schema so that tag names are shorter (thus reducing its size)?  Is there a reason it needs to be an xml file, and not in a database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can** use an XmlTextWriter.

Just open the file for writing, seek back to the start of the end element, and then append any new elements you want with the XmlTextWriter. To close the file, simply write the raw text for the end element to make the document complete and you're done.

Here's a quick and dirty example.

Starting with XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocumentElement>
    <FirstElem/>
</DocumentElement>
```

You can open it and append an element like this:

```
using (FileStream f = new FileStream(@"D:\a.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    f.Seek(-("</DocumentElement>\n".Length), SeekOrigin.End);
    using (XmlTextWriter x = new XmlTextWriter(f, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        x.WriteStartElement("Another");
        x.WriteAttributeString("attr", "value");
        x.WriteEndElement();

        // Close the file with a new terminating end-element
        x.WriteRaw("\r\n</DocumentElement>\r\n");
    }
}
```

And the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocumentElement>
    <FirstElem/>
<Another attr="value" />
</DocumentElement>
```

You may not get the indentation perfect etc, but it's valid XML. This is exactly what you'd do if writing xml as raw text to the file - but you might as well leverage the XML writer to do the formatting for you.

I'd also agree with some of the comments - it will be very beneficial to use a schema for your xml that minimises the size. Turn off indentation. Use the shortest element and attribute names you can. And if you are working on leaf elements, storing data as attributes rather than cdata will save room (`<element>data</element>` is more expensive than `<element val="data"/>` and this can be compressed further to `<e v="data"/>` - almost half the original size)

Comment: I can verify that this works, although rather than use \r\n it is better practice to use Environment.NewLine. That was my only modification. Thank you!

Comment: I did say it was a quick & dirty example! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that (as @payo's comment suggests) you could use a combination of a file stream, an [XmlTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx) (to position the stream at the appropriate element) and an [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) to write the new elements and then re-write the closing element.

Comment: He specifically says in his question that `XmlWriter` doesn't work for him.

Comment: ...and just hook up the stream (+1 chris, I was going to suggest this)

Comment: @Thomas you are right, my mistake.  I've updated it to indicate how to accomplish what the OP is after using XmlReader and XmlWriter.

Comment: @ChrisShain good point about the XmlReader (to find the right injection point). I glossed over that point. I once wrote a deserializer for a stream of data far too large to actually load into memory - using XmlReader and smart stream seeking (not all the data needed to be deserialized).